# React Native - is there a reliable Geo fencing Package that is available?

Tags: react-native, geofencing

I have been searching for a while and I haven't come across a reliable geofencing package for `react-native`. I have found the following ones: react-native-boundary, react-native-simple-native-geofencing(not fully tested). These are not very reliable and don't have good support. Furthermore, these packages do have bugs. Please advise if there is a package available.

Answer (score 3):

You can use react-native-geolocation-service available on npmjs.
With this you can use features like continuously watch position or getting current user location.

[Click here to check react-native-geolocation-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service)

For making a geo-fence calculate distance using below function by passing LatLong of user and LatLong of geo fence area..It returns radius.

[Refer guide for below function from geodatasource](https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript)

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
    return 0;
}
else {
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
    var theta = lon1-lon2;
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    if (dist > 1) {
        dist = 1;
    }
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
    if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
    return dist;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this and do you have a working solution of this ?

Comment: I have tried the one on the second link and It works.

Comment: this is not best solution, since geofencing isn't simply checking your location every second and comparing to some predefined radiuses - there are lot of fancy algorithms like decreasing frequency of checks while you are getting away from geofence to save battery - using some wrapper around Apple/Google geofencing SDK is way to go.

Comment: Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5nvMQe-fpc

Answer (score 3):

Geofencing is not trivial, there are many pitfalls that can occur, for example how to manage the differences between handset vendors, and how to achieve a good precision. It is quite difficult to have a consistent behavior accross devices and operating systems versions. So you should look to dedicated products like Herow or Radar . They both have React Native plugins, and they have free trials.

Comment: sad to hear that, not even the free solutions out there are supported anymore, another good one (paid) is transistor soft

Comment: Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5nvMQe-fpc